# "be enacted' = to take place

Tags: verbs

Why is the passive, and not the active (= "[to enact](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/enact?q=enact)"),  the equivalent of "to take place"? What's the intuition?

Comment: What alternative do you suggest? Please give some examples.

Answer (score 2):

*Enact* is transitive.  *Take place* is intransitive.

You enact something. You don't take-place something or take something place.

- The participants enacted the play.
- The play was enacted by the participants.
- The play took place.